# Python player movement

Tags: python

```
def playerMove (board,player):
    userInput = input("Enter a direction NSWE: ").upper()
    if userInput == "N":
        if (player == 0):
            board[player] = '.'
            player += 1
            board[player] = '@'
    elif userInput == "S":

        if (player(board)-1):
            board[player] = '.'
            player += 1
            board[player] = '@'
    elif userInput == "E":

        if (player < len(board)-1):
            board[player] = '.'
            player += 1
            board[player] = '@'
    elif userInput == "W":

        if (player['x'] > 0):
            board[player] = '.'
            player -= 1
            board[player] = '@'
```

I want the single player to move up, down, left,and right. I am so lost. I am a beginner and I do not know where to begin.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  What does it mean for the player to move?  What output do you get from this, and what did you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed some English issues with your post.  Please tell us what happens when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question what exactly is going on, or supposed to go on.

From your references to a board though, you might want to keep track of a x and y coordinate for your player. It seems there's just the one dimension being tracked right now, which would equate to only being able to move left or right.

You might want to look into classes for Python (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) and define a class for the board, for the player, and so on. It'll be easier to keep track of what's what, and where's where.

Comment: Can you please provide some solution to his problem, rather than asking him to study python, which I agree he/she should do.

Comment: i have a bunch of other coding i didnt think i would need to post with it. i have the x and y tracked i believe, i just don't know how to move the player after it is randomly generated in a 5x5 board.